# Azure Stream Analytics: ML Service function call in cloud job results in no output events

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-machine-learning-service

I've got a problem with an Azure Stream Analytics (ASA) job that should call an Azure ML Service function to score the provided input data.
The query was developed und tested in Visual Studio (VS) 2019 with the "Azure Data Lake and Stream Analytics Tools" Extension.
As input the job uses an Azure IoT-Hub and as output the VS local output for testing purposes (and later even with Blobstorage).
Within this environment everything works fine, the call to the ML Service function is successfull and it returns the desired response.
Using the same query, user-defined functions and aggregates like in VS in the cloud job, no output events are generated (with neither Blobstorage nor Power BI as output).
In the ML Webservice it can be seen, that ASA successfully calls the function, but somehow does not return any response data.
Deleting the ML function call from the query results in a successfull run of the job with output events.

For the deployment of the ML Webservice I tried the following (working for VS, no output in cloud):

- ACI (1 CPU, 1 GB RAM)
- AKS dev/test (Standard_B2s VM)
- AKS production (Standard_D3_v2 VM)

The inference script function schema:

- input: array
- output: record

Inference script input schema looks like:

```py
@input_schema('data', NumpyParameterType(input_sample, enforce_shape=False))
@output_schema(NumpyParameterType(output_sample))  # other parameter type for record caused error in ASA
def run(data):
    response = {'score1': 0,
                'score2': 0,
                'score3': 0,
                'score4': 0,
                'score5': 0,
                'highest_score': None}
```

And the return value:

```py
return [response]
```

The ASA job subquery with ML function call:

```sql
with raw_scores as (
select
    time, udf.HMMscore(udf.numpyfySeq(Sequence)) as score
from Sequence
)
```

and the UDF "numpyfySeq" like:

```js
// creates a N x 18 size array
function numpyfySeq(Sequence) {
    'use strict';
    var transpose = m => m[0].map((x, i) => m.map(x => x[i]));
    var array = [];
    for (var feature in Sequence) {
        if (feature != "time") {
            array.push(Sequence[feature])
        }
    }
    return transpose(array);
}
```

"Sequence" is a subquery that aggregates the data into sequences (arrays) with an user-defined aggregate.

In VS the data comes from the IoT-Hub (cloud input selected).
The "function signature" is recognized correctly in the portal as seen in the image: [Function signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmBrm.png)

I hope the provided information is sufficient and you can help me.

**Edit:**

The authentication for the Azure ML webservice is key-based.
In ASA, when selecting to use an "Azure ML Service" function, it will automatically detect and use the keys from the deployed ML model within the subscription and ML workspace.
Deployment code used (in this example for ACI, but looks nearly the same for AKS deployment):

```py
from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig, Model
from azureml.core.environment import Environment
from azureml.core.conda_dependencies import CondaDependencies
from azureml.core.webservice import AciWebservice


ws = Workspace.from_config()
env = Environment(name='scoring_env')
deps = CondaDependencies(conda_dependencies_file_path='./deps')
env.python.conda_dependencies = deps

inference_config = InferenceConfig(source_directory='./prediction/', 
                                   entry_script='score.py', 
                                   environment=env)
deployment_config = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(auth_enabled=True, cpu_cores=1, 
                                                       memory_gb=1)
model = Model(ws, 'HMM')

service = Model.deploy(ws, 'hmm-scoring', models, 
                       inference_config, 
                       deployment_config, 
                       overwrite=True,)

service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
```

with conda_dependencies:

```yaml
name: project_environment
dependencies:
  # The python interpreter version.

  # Currently Azure ML only supports 3.5.2 and later.

- python=3.7.5

- pip:
  - sklearn
  - azureml-core
  - azureml-defaults
  - inference-schema[numpy-support]
  - hmmlearn
- numpy
- pip
channels:
- anaconda
- conda-forge
```

The code used in the score.py is just a regular score operation with the loaded models and formatting like so:

```py
score1 = model1.score(data)
score2 = model2.score(data)
score3 = model3.score(data)
# Same scoring with model4 and model5

# scaling of the scores to a defined interval and determination of model that delivered highest score

response['score1'] = score1
response['score2'] = score2
# and so on
```

Comment: I don't know much about ASA, but do you have access to the logs that you could share?  Can you share any actual code? What Azure ML SDK code are you calling? How are you authenticating to Azure ML?

Comment: also please add all your code snippets as text formatted between triple back ticks (```), instead of screenshots!

Comment: Sadly I cannot provide any logs, because there are none except for the successfull start and stop of the ASA job or successfull connection to inputs, functions and outputs. Insights also only tells, that there are successfull function calls while the job is running and no errors.

Comment: Please raise an azure support request to debug on this issue, This will help you to share the details securely and work with an engineer.

Comment: The App Insights can be enabled for azure Machine Learning job. Here is the link to the documentation. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-enable-app-insights